# "When I was there, I would sunbathe / sunbathed a lot"

Tags: tense

> When I was in Sharm El-Sheikh, I .... a lot

A) Have sunbathed B) Was sunbathing C) Would sunbathe D) Sunbathed

I am certain it's either "Would sunbathe" or "Sunbathed" but can't tell which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B, C or D are grammatically correct

But there is no reason for using a continuous tense, so probably not "B". The "would sunbathe" to mean *past habit*  (= used to sunbathe) is possible, but it is a fairly rare construction. Which leaves "D" as the most likely answer.

When a continuous tense is used, we tend to use a time phrase that indicates a period of time, not a point in time (for example using "while" not "when").  It appears that the person who set this test either believes that is a strict rule, or is testing a syllabus that teaches this as a strict rule.

Similarly, it appears that the person who set the test is not aware of the "past habit" meaning of would, and is only aware (or is testing a syllabus that only teaches) the use of "would" in conditionals.

Comment: *Back then I was playing a lot of tennis* is perfectly legit in AmE. Then *when*-clause is reason enough to use it.

Comment: I said B that is grammatically correct¸hence "perfectly legit". But there is no particular reason to use a continous tense. So the answer that the examiner probably wants is probably not "B".  I realise this is treating English as a game not a means of communication. I've expressed frustration at this kind of question in other places.